# Objective-C Check if self also a subclass

Tags: objective-c, inheritance

This is in context with Objective C. I have 3 classes. 
`ClassA`, `ClassB` and `ClassC`.

`ClassB` and `ClassC` are subclasses of `ClassA`.

```
@interface ClassB : ClassA
@interface ClassC : ClassA
```

I need to make a check in `classA`, whether or not `self` is a `ClassB` or `ClassC`.

Comment: **Class Introspection** hmm?

Comment: `if ([self className] isEqualToString:@"ClassA")` or `if( [self isKindOfClass:ClassA])`

Comment: @AnoopVaidya, why create strings first?

Comment: simply tried to show all possible ways, 2nd will be good one.

Comment: I think this will break with class clusters. @AnoopVaidya

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Thanks for your answer. Was just reading your blog. Great stuff.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> I need to...

**No, you don't.** If a base class requires knowledge about its subclasses, then you have made a **huge design mistake.**

---

Anyway, this is how to check for being in a specific subclass:

```
if ([self isKindOfClass:[ClassB class]]) {
    // Class B
} else if ([self isKindOfClass:[ClassC class]]) {
    // Class C
}
```

Comment: The above-the-fold bit is quite correct. Subclass-specific behavior should go into the subclass. The subclass can always call up to super in an overridden method.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yes, exactly. Unfortunately, lot of beginners and not-so-beginners don't realize this.

Comment: That was exactly my doubt. This solution is valid if ClassB and ClassC are not subclasses. If I have to import them in base class, that defeats purpose of inheritance. +1 for clearing my doubt.

Answer (score 5):

> I need to make a check in classA, whether or not self is a ClassB or ClassC.

A better way to do that is to call some abstract method that can be defined in your subclasses:

**ClassA:**

```
- (void)doThing
{
    [self doSpecializedThing];
}

- (void)doSpecializedThing
{
    return;
}
```

**ClassB:**

```
- (void)doSpecializedThing
{
    // ClassB's specialized version of whatever ClassA needs to do
}
```

**ClassC:**

```
- (void)doSpecializedThing
{
    // ClassC's specialized version of whatever ClassA needs to do
}
```

This prevents ClassA from having to know anything specific about its subclasses, as that's pretty much always a bad idea.

You can also override `-doThing` in ClassB and ClassC and have them call `[super doThing]` in their implementation. That's not necessarily the right solution in every case, though, such as when the code in ClassA's `-doThing` relies on some behavior in the subclasses (e.g. if `-doSpecializedThing` were to return a value used in `-doThing`).

Comment: And as @Josh-Caswell points out, you can call `[super doSpecializedThing]` from the subclass to do whatever's in ClassA's implementation.

Comment: @AaronBrager Yes, of course, but that's not always the most desirable solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
if([self isKindOfClass:[ClassB class]]){
     ...
}
else if ([self isKindOfClass:[ClassC class]])
{

}
```

Hope this helps...

As H2CO3 said, bring that subclass specific behavior into the subclass itself.

Answer (score 0):

My solution in one string is:

//Do not use this class. Use subclass instead
ASSERT([NSStringFromClass([self class]) isEqualToString:@"SDDocumentsViewController"]==NO);